# Is there any way to decrypt encrypted properties in Spring Cloud config Server in other projects?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config-server

Is there any way to decrypt encrypted properties in Spring Cloud config Server in other projects?

For example, I want to decrypt "test" = "{chip}asdasdasd" without using the crypto endpoint of the spring cloud server.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot application as a client, it's easy, just add

```
encrypt:
  key: your_key
```

to `bootsrap.yaml` and Spring will handle everything else.
Problems appear when you have other clients.
Then you can try to find some libraries or create your own: [Example for TypeScript](https://github.com/ZEXSM/node-scc-config/blob/main/src/decryptors/aes-decryptor.ts)